# How to make old nostalgic looking sky in blender?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, filmic-blender

I want to make an old nostalgic looking sky that represents the 90s or 80s or even the early 2000s,
you know the exactly like images from an old photo album,

I want to make something like this
[image]

[image]

Comment: "*Nostalgic looking sky that represents the 90s or 80s*" The sky hasn't really changed appearance much throughout time. Looks like you either want a low resolution image, or some sort of color or image filter to emulate old film or low dynamic range.

Comment: Just do a sky with less pollution than today and you are set.

Comment: Do you already have an image of clouds, or do you need to make the texture? What I mean is, are you looking to make the cloud texture. the "old-school" effect, or both?

Comment: i want to add both :)